# Django how do i filter ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following M2M relationship between `OrderPage` and `Site`. How can I filter `Site` which belong to all `OrderPage`? Something like:

`Site.objects.filter(all of the orderpage).distinct()`

My model is

```
class OrderPage(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to fetch all `Site` instances except those which don't have any `OrderPage`s associated. For example:

```
Site.objects.all().exclude(orderpage__isnull=True)
```